# Punchout2go integration for c#

Tags: javascript, c#, e-commerce, checkout, api-gateway

I want to implement "*punch out*" integration in my website. I am working on a e commerce website and it required to implement "*punch out*" with help of [punchout2go.com](https://www.punchout2go.com/) .

I searched over web, but can't get any proper solution. Any help or tutorial link will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format the question

Comment: Have you any idea how to implement this ? Any little help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation was sufficient to implement punchout2go integration. just simple XML was sent as data to API and in response an URL with token was retrieved. Then i need to access that URL and boom my punchout client page was opened , i can add items to cart and after clicking on proceed, i will come back with response which will have cart items and then i need to render that cart items on my website page, and it was done.

Answer (score 0):

I apologies in advance that this is not a technical response.

If you are working with punchout2go, you should reach out to them and they will help get you sorted out. They have materials available and can get on collaborative working sessions to make sure you are getting what you need.

If you were not provided a contact, you can call them or use the chat or contact form off their website. Let them know who you are, what project you are on and that you are trying to track down a contact and need dev help getting going.

Comment: Thanks for advice Shawn . I have already tried to contact them . Got Some documents also . Documentation explains very well that how things work in punchout but no explanation for how to implement it. Basically i am working on a e commerce website which will contain some products with punchout facility . There i will provide a punchout button ,clicking which will redirect to supplier's website maintaining session and pass logged in user details on my website to supplier's website. They are asking to use cxml to send data . i have no prior experience on this . So i need some assistance to start